# Setting up a global PTR record for entire server

Tags: email, ptr-record, digital-ocean

Digital Ocean droplet running CentOS 7 with Plesk Panel installed.

Trying to improve the email deliverability and overall state of the mail server.

Want to set up a PTR record and apply this to the DNS template so that it can be applied to all domains hosted on the server.

[image: Setting up PTR records in Plesk]

Not entirely sure what I should be using to set up this record.

1. The droplet (server IP) is provided by Digital Ocean.
2. We do not use Digital Ocean's DNS for the domains hosted however.
3. We use custom nameservers that we host on another server, the root domain and GLUE records are registered via Namecheap. (Example: ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com).
4. The server's hostname is a sub-domain on the same domain as our custom nameservers. (Example: vps-01.example.com).

If I need to contact a provider to ask about the correct details to be using for the PTR record, who is it that I need to contact? Or can I source the information myself based on our set up?

*Please note: This is not a question about Plesk but specifically to do with the format and set up/provision of PTR DNS record.*

Comment: DigitalOcean uses the name of the droplet as its reverse DNS hostname. You should be able to change this when you log in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PTR records for [reverse lookups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) don't go in your domain's DNS zone. Instead, they must go into the reverse zone that IP is delegated to. In case of a single DO machine without its own netblock, that will be DOs DNS server. They should provide some kind of interface to do this.

Comment: Yes, You need to contact server provider to set up PTR record to IP. They will have a reverse zone for IP range.

Comment: Okay great, thanks Sven and Sunil. I'll raise a ticket with DO and see what they have to say.

Comment: Just read the docs. It's explained (can't link because apparently their system is stupid and doesn't have static links).

Comment: Thanks Sven. To clarify for anyone else, in my case, in order to have a valid PTR record set by DO, the hostname of the DO droplet had to be a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) which mine is already as per set as the server hostname in Plesk (example: vps-01.example.com) which can be anything you like - but if you want reverse DNS working as well, the hostname of the DO droplet has to be a FQDN that matches the one set in Plesk.